# Authentication problem during upgrade

Tags: upgrade, authentication

I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. When I start upgrading, a window appeared with the following message:

> authentication failed there may be a problem with the network or with a server

Please guide me on how can I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this(not best way to solve this problem but it is working):

Download Ubuntu 11.04 and make LiveCD on pendrive or cd/dvd.

Boot LiveCD.

Use "upgrade Ubuntu" in options.

Comment: This method works very well, and will resolve problems identified.